# How to set combo box value in WPF using MVVM architecture

Tags: c#, mvvm, combobox, wpf-controls

I created a POC in WPF MVVM architecture.In which I used combo box control you can see in the code below.

```
 <ComboBox Name="DeptCombo" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding DepartmentList,Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentDepartment,Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="DepartmentName">
</ComboBox>
```

here CurrentDepartment is a property of Department class.

Everything is fine, I filled that combo , saved that combo value in the database, But the only problem I was facing is, I am not able to set the saved database value in that combo.I don't get any solution regarding that.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Add **UpdateSourceTrigger**

```
  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentDepartment,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Еhe code should look something like this:

```
  class ViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Datas { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>()
    {
        "FF", "AA", "BB"
    };

    private string currentItem;
    public string CurrentItem
    {
        get => currentItem;
        set
        {
            currentItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentItem");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop="")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```

Example with Model:
PersonModel.cs:

```
   class PersonModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel.cs:

```
 class ViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<PersonModel> Datas { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<PersonModel>()
        {
            new PersonModel(){Age = 10, Name="Tom"},
            new PersonModel(){Age = 10, Name="Mark"},
        };

        private PersonModel currentItem;
        public PersonModel CurrentItem
        {
            get => currentItem;
            set
            {
                currentItem = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentItem");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop="")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Datas}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              Height="100" Width="100">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Hi @typical please explain your solution in detail why I use UpdateSourceTrigger here

Comment: @Shubham, it needs to update your ComboBox property, when ViewModel CurrentDepartment will changed. UpdateSourceTrigger is intended to set the logic for updating data.

Comment: it is not working do I need to add something more in view model regarding PropertyChanged

Comment: @Shubham, I added an example in the response

Comment: perfect @typical, when I bind list of string type variable in combo it is working fine, but when I use list of class type object then the problem is occur, in my case  ItemsSource="{Binding DepartmentList,Mode=TwoWay}" here Department list is the list of class Department  and  SelectedItem="{Binding path=CurrentDepartment,Mode=TwoWay}" here CurrentDepartment is a property of class Department type

Comment: @Shubham, can you show source code of ViewModel and Department?

Comment: @Shubham, you can bind a property of class in ComboBox.ItemTemplate, not in ComboBox

Comment: @Shubham, see example with a DataTemplate

Comment: Hi @typical please see I shared my Department Class and view model class

Comment: Do you mean we can set combo value by DataTemplate?

Comment: @Shubham, you need to add an ItemTemplate

Comment: @Shubham, yes, because ComboBox can't understand display logic and we need to create it

Answer (score 0):

Department  Class :

```
 public class Department : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertychanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private int id;
    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; OnPropertychanged("Id"); }
    }

    private string departmentName;
    public string DepartmentName
    {
        get { return departmentName; }
        set { departmentName = value; OnPropertychanged("DepartmentName"); }
    }

    private bool isActive;
    public bool IsActive
    {
        get { return isActive; }
        set { isActive = value; OnPropertychanged("IsActive"); }
    }
}
```

View Model :

```
private ObservableCollection<Department> departmentList;
    public ObservableCollection<Department> DepartmentList
    {
        get { return departmentList; }
        set { departmentList = value; OnPropertyChanged("DepartmentList"); }
    }

 private Department currentDepartment;
    public Department CurrentDepartment
    {
        get { return currentDepartment; }
        set { currentDepartment = value; OnPropertyChanged("CurrentDepartment"); }
    }

 private void DepartmentPop()
    {
        DepartmentList = new ObservableCollection<Department> 
                (objDepartmentService.GetAll());
    }
```